# Requesting multiple permissions using dialoglow

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I've been developing actions using the Dialogflow API. I get how to ask for a single permission (like SIGN_IN, PERMISSION, etc.) at a time, but I wanted to know how to ask multiple permissions at the same time? Does one try them sequentially (i.e. ask for one and once it's accepted or rejected, try the next), or is there a way through which multiple permissions can be asked concurrently (maybe like `askPermissions('SIGN_IN', 'PERMISSION')`)?

The use case is that the action requires multiple permissions before it can be successfully executed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Permissions is an array, so it can take more than 1 string. Like this:

```
const options = {
   context: 'Whatever text you add here will explain to the user why you're asking to use their location.',
   permissions: ['DEVICE_PRECISE_LOCATION','NAME'],
};
conv.ask(new Permission(options));
```